# Unknown provider: $mdThemingProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-material, bower

So, i'm trying to use angular-material but when i want inject $mdThemingProvider i get this error: `Unknown provider: $mdThemingProvider`.

And if I remove the `$mdThemingProvider` the angular-material styles are not working.

My module:

```
    angular.module('bookStoreApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.router'])
.config([
  '$stateProvider', 
  '$urlRouterProvider', 
  '$mdThemingProvider',
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $mdThemingProvider) {
    $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
    .primaryPalette('blue')
    .accentPalette('red');

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider// home page
    .state('/', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
      controller: 'BookControllers'
    });
  }
  ]);
```

My references:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/angular-material/angular-material.min.css">
  <script src="libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="libs/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="libs/angular-aria/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="libs/angular-messages/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
  <script src="libs/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
```

My bower.json dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
"angular": "^1.6.3",
"angular-material": "^1.1.3",
"angular-ui-router": "^0.4.2"
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You need to injector `ngMaterial` module when defining `bookStoreApp` module as `$mdThemingProvider` is defined in it.

```
 angular.module('bookStoreApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.router', 'ngMaterial'])
```

instead of

```
angular.module('bookStoreApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.router'])
```